# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters - Python and Spyder

Tags: python, utf-8, char, spyder

I am trying to follow an NLP example from:
https://blog.insightdatascience.com/how-to-solve-90-of-nlp-problems-a-step-by-step-guide-fda605278e4e

The data set and jupyternotebook file can be found here: https://github.com/hundredblocks/concrete_NLP_tutorial/blob/master/NLP_notebook.ipynb

The provided code is given for Python 2. However, I tried to adapt to Python 3 and hit an UnicodeEncodeError.

**I tried on Python 2 and it works as expected.

NOTE: for this tutorial, I installed TensorFlow (CPU), Keras as well as the NLTK package. I also took out "codecs" since it's not needed in Python3

I will only show up to the part that it failed. I did not used JupyterNotebook but Spyder instead.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import keras
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
#import codecs 

input_file = open("socialmedia_relevant_cols.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace')
output_file = open("socialmedia_relevant_cols_clean.csv", "w")

def sanitize_characters(raw, clean):    
     for line in input_file:
     out = line
     output_file.write(line)

sanitize_characters(input_file, output_file)
```

This is the error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-1c76dfb0b166>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Timothy Cumberland/Desktop/concrete_NLP_tutorial-master/concrete_NLP_tutorial-master/NLP_tutorial.py', wdir='C:/Users/Timothy Cumberland/Desktop/concrete_NLP_tutorial-master/concrete_NLP_tutorial-master')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlow\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlow\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Timothy Cumberland/Desktop/concrete_NLP_tutorial-master/concrete_NLP_tutorial-master/NLP_tutorial.py", line 26, in <module>
    sanitize_characters(input_file, output_file)

  File "C:/Users/Timothy Cumberland/Desktop/concrete_NLP_tutorial-master/concrete_NLP_tutorial-master/NLP_tutorial.py", line 24, in sanitize_characters
    output_file.write(line)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\TensorFlow\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 64-65: character maps to <undefined>
```

I am using Windows 10, Anaconda 4.5.0, Anaconda Navigator 1.8.2, Spyder 3.2.8 and Jupyter Notebook 5.4.0

I am not a complete beginner when it comes to coding but this is the first time I am learning Python for data analysis so I hope it's not something terribly obvious between Python 2 and 3.

I tried the `chcp 65001` on my Window's cmd but it did not seem to help.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Try opening the `output_file` with the `encoding='utf-8'` parameter as well. I also recommend dropping the `errors='replace'` parameter; if this gives you a new UnicodeError, try to find out the actual codec of the file.

Comment: That actually worked!!! Thank you. However, I am baffled though: I put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of the script and i still have to specify the encoding for every single text files?

Comment: This is a common misconception. This line is the encoding declaration of the source code. It has nothing to do with the encoding of input/output, the default of which depends on the environment.